# Collection persists but doesn't appears in other side

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many relationship in Hibernate. When i relate one objectA with two objectsB, the objectA.getObjectB() returns the two elements sucessfully (including database), but objectB.getObjectA() doesn´t return objectA. Only after a new session that is going to work.

```
@Entity
public class ObjectA implements java.io.Serializable {

    private List<ObjectB> objectsB;

    ...

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "db_objectA_objectB", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "idObjectA", updatable = false)}, inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "idObjectB", updatable = false)})
    public List<ObjectB> getObjectsB() {
        return objectsB;
    }

    public void setObjectsB(List<ObjectB> objectsB) {
        this.objectsB = objectsB;
    }
}

@Entity
public class ObjectB implements java.io.Serializable {

    private List<ObjectA> objectsA;

    ...

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "objectsB", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<ObjectA> getObjectsA() {
        return objectsA;
    }

    public void setObjectsA(List<ObjectA> objectsA) {
        this.objectsA= objectsA;
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be the behavior of hibernate. It won't populate both direction of entity relationship, just one direction in which you queried it in

Comment: Does it throw any exceptions ? or its returning null?

Answer (score 1):

Keeping both sides of the relationship consistent is responsibility of application code, not the responsibility of Hibernate. In JPA 2.0 specification this is told with following words:

> Note that it is the application that bears responsibility for
>   maintaining the consistency of run- time relationships—for example,
>   for insuring that the “one” and the “many” sides of a bidirectional
>   relationship are consistent with one another when the application
>   updates the relationship at runtime.